# String (indexes) input from text box to int

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get words like "first" "second" "third" from an input box and converting the words into ints. So "first" = 1, "second" = 2, and so on. Is there a way to do that with Jquery?
This is what I have tried so far.

```
 var functionGet = function(strSelector) {
        var input = $(strSelector).val();
        input = parseInt(input);
        return input;
      };
```

But this clearly doesn't work because "first" is not the same as "one"

Comment: please take a careful look at [parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp), it certainly doesn't do magic ;)

Comment: ... neither does jQuery

Comment: Would be a nice one for codegolf.stackexchange.com with mandatory use of jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be with a legend

```
var numbers = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
  third: 3
}

var inputVal = $('input').val()
var intNum = numbers[inputVal]
```

Comment: you could also add other words that mean 1 to the legend like `{one:1, first:1, uno:1}` and they would all work

Answer (score 0):

One way is write an array like ["first", "second", "third"...] and you can do find index of and print the matching index + 1 if index is > -1

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this automatically.

Instead, you'll need to create some sort of mapping dictionary that has the word(s) for each number and what number they convert to.

Something like this:

```js
const dict = [
  ['zero'],
  ['one', 'first'],
  ['two', 'second']
  // etc
];

function convertWordToNumber(word) {
  for (let i in dict) {
    if (dict[i].includes(word)) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  
  return 'unknown';
}

['zero', 'second', 'one']
  .forEach(w => console.log(convertWordToNumber(w)));
```

In this case, the number is the index of the array, so you'd have to include `zero` (though if you want nothing to match it, you could include an empty `[]` instead).

Then, for converting, it loops through each, checking all the words. If it finds a match, it'll return that index which is the number form of that word.